# Identical Strings won't match?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to make a simple login program for a bigger project.

This code:

```
 def _login():#Login Function
        username = input("Username:\n")
        password = input("Please enter your password:\n")
        with open("logins", "r") as log: 
          for line in log:
            compound = str(username + password)
            a = line 
            b = str(re.sub(':', '', a))
            if a == compound:
              print("Success")
_login() searches through a text file where **user:pass** are on individual lines displayed as such in the bold text.
```

This then takes the string of your input username and password, concats it and does the same with the usernames/passes on file, exempt the "**:**" which is filtered via regex.

*The problem:*

The combined string that the user inputs(var ***compound***) and the filtered string from the text file(var ***a***) doesn't return true when compared even if they're both equal to user *"UserPass"*

How would I fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried printing the `repr` of each string? I think you'll find that, as the interpreter tells you, they are not equal.

Comment: Ah crap, I did type()... :P

Comment: I GOT IT THANK YOU LOL! The passwords on file contained an instance of "\n"!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already found an answer.
But I would like to say that you better use 'b' for comparison instead of 'a'.
Cause you should've removed ':' for some kind of reason. :)

Comment: ......... damn it It's repl.it... Chromebooks and Betas! Makes for bad readability. Thanks LOL